# Deleting a work sheet from excel 2010 file using c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Excel Interop Deleting a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678736/net-excel-interop-deleting-a-worksheet)

I have an EXCEL file in my C drive.How can i delete one of the work sheet from that file using c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678736/net-excel-interop-deleting-a-worksheet gets you the delete call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interop with Excel by adding the Microsoft.Office.Interop library to your project.  You can access the worksheets through a workbook object and call delete on a specified index.  Also, remember to do some cleaning up afterwards.  I find that Excel likes to linger in the background after the program is done running if not handled properly.