# Delete a single sheet in Excel using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

Due to some concurrency issues, I have been forced to create a workbook with multiple sheets. At the end of the execution, some sheets will have data and some wont. I create the sheets using an Execute SQL Task.

I am trying to loop through the workbook and delete the sheets which dont have more than a single row. In other words, delete the sheet if row count is not greater than 1. Any pointers on this question will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details on my question. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Following is the script task that I got from MSDN. I modified it to a point where it can get to the excel sheet and make a count of the rows, now all I want to do is when the count = 1 then delete the sheet. Can someone help me here?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_c346c80b4e6747688383c47a9f3e6f78.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion



            public void Main()
        {
            string count = "";
            string fileToTest;
            string tableToTest;
            string connectionString;

            fileToTest = Dts.Variables["ExcelFile"].Value.ToString();
            tableToTest = Dts.Variables["ExcelTable"].Value.ToString();

            Dts.Variables["ExcelTableExists"].Value = false;

                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                "Data Source=" + fileToTest + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
                string SQL = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM [" + tableToTest + "$]";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            count = reader[0].ToString();
                            //if (count = 1)

                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                //return count;
            }

       }
}
```

**EDIT**

On further investigation, I found that I would need to add the excel interop assembly for this to work. I dont have that option because this solution will be ported to 140 different machines.

Comment: I've never tried adding or removing worksheets from an SSIS package, but if I had to do it my first thought would be to use a Script Task (or even an external script). Then the question becomes, [how to delete a worksheet from .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678736/net-excel-interop-deleting-a-worksheet)

Comment: This is the direction I am working on right now. I hope to set it up completely and blog about it to help someone else in the same situation.

Comment: Will there always be a fixed number of sheets? or is this dynamic?

Comment: Yes. It will always be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you cannot delete a sheet in an Excel using OLEDB, the best you can do is clear it of data using the DROP Table command

```
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                     "Data Source=" + fileToTest + 
                     ";Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

string SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [" + tableToTest + "$]";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand CountCmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
    {
        int RecordCount = (int)CountCmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (RecordCount == 1)
        {
            SQL = "DROP TABLE [" + tableToTest + "$]";
            using (OleDbCommand DropCmd = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
            {
                DropCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

NOTE: The use of `Mode=ReadWrite`. You may include/exclude the `HDR=Yes/No` but you must not include `IMEX=1` if you want read/write access to the Workbook

BTW: There's no need to use a OleDbDataReader to read a single scalar result, use ExecuteScalar() instead.

The only way around this using OleDB is to copy the data you want to retain into a new excel file and replace the original one. If you do this however you will lose any formulas or formatting.

Comment: I wont have any formulas or anything on the sheets. Its just very simple data. I will test your code and get back to you asap..Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I tried your code and it ran fine. But the problem is, it does not remove the sheet itself, it just clears any data in it. I noticed the same behavior in Execute SQL Task where I issue the DROP TABLE command. This is a KNOWN behavior and I read a lot of people with the same problem.

Comment: Ah, my bad! Jumped straight to the code without reading your warning. Thanks for the help anyways.