# How to delete an excel worksheet programmatically VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, worksheet

I tried following to permanently delete a worksheet from an excel workbook, however it is not working as expected,

```
CType(oWB1.Sheets("ABC"), Excel.Worksheet).Delete()
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678736/net-excel-interop-deleting-a-worksheet) question could be of assistance?

Comment: Did you save the work book after delete the sheet?

Comment: Yes I did save the workbook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
oWB1.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
oWB1.Sheets("ABC").Delete
oWB1.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: If `Option Strict` is on then the second line will throw a late binding error; use `TryCast(oWB.Sheets("ABC"), Excel.Worksheet).Delete()` instead

Answer (score 0):

How many worksheets left after you delete the worksheet "ABC" ?

```
oWB1.Sheets("ABC").Delete()
```

Comment: `Worksheet.Delete()` will not delete the sheet if it is the only one in the book.