# Excel worksheet won't delete [C#, WPF, VS 2010]

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, visual-studio-2010

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

// creating new WorkBook within Excel application
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Report.xlsx");

// Get current worksheet and clear it
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[1];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets[2];
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
worksheet1.Delete();
worksheet2.Delete();
app.DisplayAlerts = true;

//app.Worksheets[1].Delete();
//app.Worksheets[2].Delete();
workbook.Save();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)app.Worksheets.Add(); ;
// storing header part in Excel
for (int i = 1; i < mydatatable.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = mydatatable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName.ToString();
}
// storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (int i = 0; i < mydatatable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < mydatatable.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = mydatatable.Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
    worksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
}

Excel.Range chartRange;

Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)worksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = worksheet.get_Range("C1", "E20");
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet,"Chart");

workbook.Save();
workbook.Close(misValue);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
app.Quit();
```

It creates the new worksheet perfectly, but doesn't delete the old one first. I even have two codes to delete it and it doesn't. I have more than one sheet in the app.

EDIT: I just noticed that the first time I run the code it deletes the given sheets, but if I run it a second time (etc) it won't delete them anymore and gives me error, because aparently EXCEL proccess is still open in the background for some reason, altough I use "app.Quit()". Please help!

Comment: do you get any exceptions? can you try to add a try and catch around your code and see what happens? EDIT: I assume that it gives  you this error, because the second time you run it, it crashes somewhere before the `app.Quit();` and then you can see that the process is still active in the task manager.

Comment: @Apostrofix 2014-09-16 10:45:46.1701|ERROR|PSN.MainWindow|Exception message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC , and I'm sure it is cuz of EXCEL being open,  ALTOUGH I force close the thread from TaskManager and I still get the error if I run the code again. I just can't understand why Excel isn't closed.

Comment: have you tried to debug it line by line, just to see exactly where it crashes? perhaps the problem is that you might need to refresh the document before you continue with the rest. or simply to reopen it again(it's just a guess).

Comment: @Apostrofix yes, it crashes on "chartPage.Location(Excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsNewSheet,"Chart");" , probably because it doesn't delete that page?, but why! because it's a chart-type of worksheet? how can i get around this?

Comment: the first thing that i could think of is that you have to save the workbook(and eventually refresh/reload/reopen it again) after you create the worksheet(possibly after you delete as well). then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems could be that you have one worksheet when you're trying to delete it.  Make sure that you're not deleting last worksheet or it won't work.  So, create new one, then delete old one; not the other way around.

**EDIT:**

Try this code:

```
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
worksheetdel.Delete();
app.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/678795/2006048

Comment: At a point I had 5 worksheets and was deleting only worksheets[1], which it obviously didn't do :(

Comment: ok, I'll edit the main thread, I just notice it deletes the sheets the FIRST TIME I run the code, but if I try a second time, it doesn't work anymore, and it's because for some reason EXCEL is stil open in the background, altough I have an "app.Quit" there.....I'll update the main thread